# C++ multiple definition of function

Tags: c++

I'm writing library for arduino for communication with specific hardware. I've got 4 files (main.cpp DCB.cpp, DCB.h, ubus_cmd.h). In DCB.cpp I include header file (`#include "DCB.h"`) and in DCB.h i define it (`#ifndef DCB_H #define DCB_H` ). In main file (main.cpp) I include the library (`#include "DCB.h"`). But i still get error of multiple definition at constructor of DCB.cpp file. Errors are saying ("first definition here", "multiple definition of DCB::DCB()")

Comment: Is the error message to cryptic to understand?

Comment: So how can we tell that you didn't, for example, write the ctor twice? It's impossible to tell here.

Comment: So, C++ or C? Do not tag questions with both tags.

Comment: You need to post the code and the exact error message. Otherwise it is just guess work.

Comment: Have you by any chance **implemented** `DCB::DCB()` in both `DCB.h` and `DCB.cpp`? By **implemented**, I mean - not just declared.

Comment: Thats unreadable. Put it in the Question and use a code block (indent by 4 spaces)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the title says it all. You're not allowed to define a single function twice, unless it's `inline`. Clearly your constructor has two definitions.

The things you said about header inclusion do help to prevent accidental double definition, but they are not sufficient.